# Bootstrap and Respond.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap in a Wordpress theme and I need to support IE8

I need to load respond.js in wordpress so I can support IE8

I can't get respond.js to load correctly.

I've tired:

A respond.js plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/respondjs/

Using wp_enqueue_script to add resond.js and

Adding the respond.js inline in the html.

Has anyone added respond.js to wordpress, what is the best way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen this? Unsure if it will help but has some good info in it

http://davekiss.com/ie8-respond-js-and-wordpress/

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.